# Sphere and nonuniform object intersection

Tags: geometry

I have two objects: A sphere and an object. Its an object that I created using surface reconstruction - so we do not know the equation of the object. I want to know the intersecting points on the sphere when the object and the sphere intersect. If we had a sphere and a cylinder, we could solve for the equation and figure out the area and all that but the problem here is that the object is not uniform.

Is there a way to find out the intersecting points or area on the sphere?

Comment: I'm probably being pedantic, but just to be sure: you want the 2d surface area on a reconstructed surface (which presumably may be 3d) that lies within a 3d sphere?

Comment: No. I am actually after the points so that I can transfer the points on the sphere to the object and reconstruct the surface to get the complete surface (as I said below, just like when you take a bite off an apple).

Comment: Oh, so it's a constructive solid geometry sort of thing? Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by finding the intersection of triangles with the sphere. First find the intersection of each triangle's plane and the sphere, which gives a circle. Then find the circle's intersection/s with the triangle edges in 2D using line/circle tests. The result will be many arcs which I guess you could approximate with lines. I'm not really sure where to go from here without knowing the end goal.

If it's surface area you're after, maybe a numerical approach would be better. I'd cover the sphere in points and count the number inside the non-uniform object. To find if a point is inside, maybe trace outwards and count the intersections with the surface (if it's odd, the point is inside). You could use the stencil buffer for this if you wanted (similar to stencil shadows).

If you want the volume of intersection a quick google search gives "carve", a mesh based CSG library.

Comment: Actually the ultimate goal is to use the sphere as a cutter. I want to transfer the points on the sphere to the object and reconstruct the surface to get the complete surface (just like when you take a bite off an apple).

Comment: OK, so what you're trying to do a reconstruction of a point based model, then a CSG operation with the reconstruction but instead of keeping the triangle data, put point back into your original representation and reconstruct again? I would use image-based CSG from 6 different (cube face) directions, keeping the pixel positions on the sphere. Then the pixels become your points. Maybe use "OpenCSG"?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with triangles versus the sphere will give you the points of intersection.

You can take the arcs of intersection with each surface and combine them to make fences around the sphere. Ideally your reconstructed object will be in [winged-edge format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge) so you could just step from one fence segment to the next, but with reconstructed surfaces I guess you might need to apply some slightly fuzzy logic.

You can determine which side of each fence is inside the reconstructed object and which side is out by factoring in the surface normals along the fence.

You can then cut the sphere along the fences and add the internal bits to the display.

For the other side of things you could remove any triangle completely inside the sphere and cut those that intersect.